# Proper Practice when Calling a Function with a Return value From Button Click

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">

            function add(a,b) {
               var result = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)
               return result
            }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="text" name="numberOne" id="txtNumberOne" />
      <input type="text" name="numberTwo" id="txtNumberTwo" />
     <!-- <input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Add" /> -->
     <button id="btnClick">Add</button>

     <p id="answer"></p>  

<script>
    document.getElementById("btnClick").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var view = add(document.getElementById('txtNumberOne').value, document.getElementById('txtNumberTwo').value )
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = view;
});
</script>


   </body>
</html>
```

**Question:**

When calling a function with a return value, how would I go about capturing the result and displaying it?

The above code does that, however, it is **proper practice** to do it that way? I created an addListnerEvent, and when the user clicks the button it calls the function which returns the answer, the innerHTML displays the answer. If not, what is the proper practice?

Comment: I see no problem with it.

Comment: This isn't something that has a "proper practice".  You just do whatever suits your requirements.  What you've shown above is perfectly fine if you just want to populate an element with the result.

Comment: @NeilMunro - Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it's not a proper practice? aka what are you trying to improve?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia - I'm not trying to improve anything, I'm learning javascript on my own, and I have a background in C#/Java, and work like this is done inside the button handler, but, I wanted to know what was proper practice, I don't want to continue, only to find out, what I did was wrong or considered improper.

Comment: I would say that the call to `add` is pretty messy, try to get those two values in two different lines for clarity. I'd also clean them up (parseInt) when retrieving them, not before suming them up. Lastly, `id`s are considered bad practice for quite some time now in HTML, the preferred method are classes

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia - How would you correct the above code, could you show me?

Comment: ids are perfectly fine.... How to improve it is just personal opinion.

Comment: sorry I'm on my mobile now and that'd be pretty painful, I'll try it tomorrow

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia - Thanks

Comment: http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia - If I use the button class instead of IDs, could I still use the same button handler? How would I implement one?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia ... What?? That is just crazy talk. ID's are definitely not considered bad practice, and classes does not in any way replace them. They are two very different things, who happen to have overlapping usage areas in some cases. Seriously, as a guy who works with automated testing, I encourage you to use as many ID's as possible!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. Note however that I'm lacking some relevant information. Few notes:

- This is just an answer but there are many different kind of answers
- I'll assume that the two inputs are indeed unique each other. So you don't want a sum(input[i]), but you want a sum(a, b). It would be really different otherwise
- I will use the `document.querySelector()` syntax, which is more similar to what jQuery and other libraries use
- The form is completely meaningless. HTML is semantic, so give it its semantics back. I'll assume this is some kind of bank statement, but please change the names to suit your project

[See the demo it in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6b476f7/). Code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- inputs belong to a form -->
    <form class="totalpayment">
      <input class="paid" type="text" name="numberOne" />
      <input class="due" type="text" name="numberTwo" />
      <button class="gettotal">Add</button>
    </form>
    <p class="total"></p>  

    <!-- scripts are better at the end of the body -->
    <script>
      // Retrieve a number from an input element
      function getNumber(selector) {
        var rawValue = document.querySelector(selector).value;
        return parseInt(rawValue);
      }

      // Sum the value when submitting the form
      document.querySelector(".totalpayment").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var paid = getNumber('.paid');
        var due = getNumber('.due');
        document.querySelector(".total").innerHTML = paid + due;
      });
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Or with jQuery, using it makes your life much easier and it's really commonplace. [See the demo it in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6b476f7/). Code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form class="totalpayment">
      <input class="paid" type="text" name="numberOne" />
      <input class="due" type="text" name="numberTwo" />
      <button>Add</button>
    </form>
    <p class="total"></p>  

    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Sum the value when submitting the form
      $(".totalpayment").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var paid = parseInt($('.paid').val());
        var due = parseInt($('.due').val());
        $(".total").html(paid + due);
      });
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Both addEventListener and innerHTML are best practices currently when using no library (much better than `element.onclick` or inline `onclick` anyway).