# Using Classes Instead of IDs in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565544/proper-practice-when-calling-a-function-with-a-return-value-from-button-click#comment51087977_31565544), I was advised not to use IDs, intead use classes in HTML forms for buttons.

I'm new to HTML5 and Javascript, so how I use the button class, and assign an event handler to the button?

**Possible Solution:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Button Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<button name="button" value="OK" type="button">Click Me</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would then use document.getElementByName() and assign a button handler, correct?

Comment: the post you mention just says don't use `id` selectors in css, using `id`s is fine

Comment: using id's anywhere where id's are appropriate is fine

Comment: @depperm - so in the other post, my code is okay?

Comment: yes, in fact most of the comments say it was fine code, in the future if you just want a code review try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, SO is for questions about why something isn't working as expected

Comment: @JaromandaX - So the way I use it in my previous code is fine?

Comment: `document.getElementByName` doesn’t exist. You mean `document.getElementsByName` (plural), which returns a `NodeList` with multiple elements.

Comment: I have no opinion on code snippets

Comment: I'm confused though, the question is about using classes instead of id's - yet no classes were harmed in the asking of the question

Comment: use classes to style multiple elements in the same way, use ids to distinguish between those elements (or to override styles)

Comment: @JaromandaX - I'm just confused, one comment said using Ids was bad others say its fine, I've got no idea.

Comment: @Pete- the way I used ids in my previous post, is fine?

Comment: that's the problem with opinions, they're just like a-holes, everyone has one :p

Comment: to put your mind at rest, I've looked at the previous post and the use of ID's is not only fine, but I wouldn't do it any other way

Comment: @JaromandaX - Much appreciated!

Comment: @Nexusfactor Ids are perfectly fine and depending on what you are doing, usually better.  Not sure what that francesco was on about, I don't think they really know what they are doing if they think ids are bad practice.  If you are going to be processing the same action on a lot of elements, then I would use a class then you can get element by the class name and loop through the array (rather than selecting each element by id), otherwise getting an element by its id will be better for performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seriously, anyone saying that:

> ids are considered bad practice for quite some time now in HTML, the preferred method are classes

...are plain wrong! id's and classes have their separate usage areas, which in some cases overlap. For automated testing, and css, ID's are extremely useful. Never be afraid to use them!

As an answer to your question, there are several options. Either find the element in javascript, and assign a button handler, or simply add an onclick-function, and assign it directly in your button tag, like this:

```
<button ... onclick="functionToBeCalled()">Click Me</button>
```

then you just define the function you'd like to execute in javaScript.